# Same enum values for multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

I need to do something like this:

```
class PlanetEdge < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum :first_planet [ :earth, :mars, :jupiter]
  enum :second_planet [ :earth, :mars, :jupiter]
end
```

Where my table is a table of edges but each vertex is an integer.

However, it seems the abvove is not possible in rails. What might be an alternative to making string columns?

Comment: Maybe this can help. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17511

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it makes extract the planet as another model?

```
class Planet < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum type: %w(earth mars jupiter)
end

class PlanetEdge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :first_planet, class_name: 'Planet'
  belongs_to :second_planet, class_name: 'Planet'
end
```

You can create a PlanetEdge by using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`:

```
class PlanetEdge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :first_planet, class_name: 'Planet'
  belongs_to :second_planet, class_name: 'Planet'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :first_planet
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :second_planet
end

PlanetEdge.create(
  first_planet_attributes: { type: 'mars' },
  second_planet_attributes: { type: 'jupiter' }
)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would create() a PlanetEdge this way?

Comment: I updated the answer. If this looks too complicated, you can also write some method like `create_for_planets(first_planet_type, second_planet_type)`, which will do all the work

Answer (score 15):

If you're running rails 5.0 or greater as per http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

You can use the :_prefix or :_suffix options when you need to define multiple enums with same values. If the passed value is true, the methods are prefixed/suffixed with the name of the enum. It is also possible to supply a custom value:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
    enum status: [:active, :archived], _suffix: true
    enum comments_status: [:active, :inactive], _prefix: :comments
end
```

With the above example, the bang and predicate methods along with the associated scopes are now prefixed and/or suffixed accordingly:

```
conversation.active_status!
conversation.archived_status? # => false

conversation.comments_inactive!
conversation.comments_active? # => false
```

Comment: This is only for rails version > 5

Comment: What would you do if you wanted to use the same enum for two different columns?

Comment: What tripped me up is that the official documentation does not prefix the parameters `_suffix` and `_prefix` with an underscore. The code however relies on the underscores being there.

Comment: for rails 7 `enum comments_status: { active: 0, inactive: 1 },  _prefix: : comments ` working well